# How to prevent a button to be a dropdown menu in tinymce

Tags: html, tinymce

[image]

I want to have an editor, that only allows bulleted "disc" lists. Since I only need a single list type, the button should not be a dropdown. How do I specify, that the list button should be a button, not a dropdown?

Current code:

```
<script>
    tinyMCE.PluginManager.add('stylebuttons', function (editor, url) {
        ['pre', 'p', 'code', 'h1', 'h2', 'h3', 'h4', 'h5', 'h6'].forEach(function (name) {
            editor.addButton("style-" + name, {
                tooltip: "Toggle " + name,
                text: name.toUpperCase(),
                onClick: function () { editor.execCommand('mceToggleFormat', false, name); },
                onPostRender: function () {
                    var self = this, setup = function () {
                        editor.formatter.formatChanged(name, function (state) {
                            self.active(state);
                        });
                    };
                    editor.formatter ? setup() : editor.on('init', setup);
                }
            })
        });
    });

    tinymce.init({
        selector: 'textarea',
        plugins: "link advlist code stylebuttons",
        advlist_bullet_styles: "disc",
        target_list: false,
        link_title: false,
        menubar: false,
        statusbar: false,
        height: 600,
        valid_elements: "p,br,b,i,a,h1,ul,li",
        toolbar: 'undo redo | bold, italic | style-h1, bullist | link | code'

    });
</script>
```

Comment: I found out, that my issue is using "advlist" plugin. Using "lists" instead does not create a dropdown. If you know how to solve this issue generally, please do answer anyway.